# How do I make a villager sell something that can break a specific block in 1.13?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a map in minecraft java edition version 1.13.1 and I want to spawn a silent, invulnerable, no AI villager that trades an iron sword for a diamond pickaxe that can only break iron bars. I've tried to use the command

```
/summon villager ~ ~1 ~ {Invulnerable:1,Silent:1,NoAI:1,CustomName:"\"insert name\"",Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:iron_sword,Count:1},sell:{id:diamond_pickaxe,},rewardExp:0b,maxUses:1}]}}
```

but it doesn't make the pickaxe able to break iron bars. How do I make it so that it can?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You just have to put the NBT of the item in the NBT of the villager trade. I think the wiki even gives you a tree view you can click through. Or look up example commands.

Comment: @FabianRöling I've tried to use the digminecraft villager trade generator, and tweak it a little. But the result makes that either it trades an iron sword for nothing, or an iron sword for just a normal pick. Could you give me an example command? I've already tried looking it up but they were all for 1.9 or earlier.

Comment: Please write the commands you tried and their behaviour into the question. And since you have an NBT tag for the sold item, just put the data of it into that.

Comment: @FabianRöling Alright. Done. I don't really know how to use NBT tags and all that. I just copy/pasted the command from digminecraft.com. Could you give me a command that might work?

Comment: You didn't put anything into the item NBT. Ah whatever, I'll just write your solution, that's easier than this discussion.

Comment: Yeah, I just copied and pasted from digminecraft.com

Comment: For future questions you'll have to at least try to solve it yourself. The Minecraft wiki and Google are your friends.

Comment: I did try to solve it myself, I just didn't know how to use NBT tags.

Comment: Well, then look it up.

Comment: I did look it up. I already said that I looked it up but all the other solutions were for 1.9 and earlier.

Comment: google.com/search?q=minecraft+1.13+commands+tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tags for the item go into a tag called `tag` (not confusing at all):

```
/summon villager ~ ~1 ~ {Invulnerable:1,Silent:1,NoAI:1,CustomName:"\"insert name\"",Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:iron_sword,Count:1},sell:{id:diamond_pickaxe,Count:1,tag:{CanDestroy:["minecraft:crafting_table"]}},rewardExp:0b,maxUses:1}]}}
```

Comment: Also, interesting way to give an entity a name. I didn't know that `"\"name\""` worked, I always used `"{\"text\":\"name\"}"`. That's the complete JSON format, which also allows other things, like colour.

Comment: Also, this question: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/294228/minecraft-how-do-i-give-a-villager-trades-with-custom-nbt-tags