# I can't figure out how to make a villager give a named item that can only break certain blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been trying to make an adventure map in minecraft and I can't figure out how to make a villager trade a wooden pickaxe with a name and can only break certain blocks with it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I give a villager trades with custom NBT tags](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/294228/how-do-i-give-a-villager-trades-with-custom-nbt-tags)

Comment: What have you already tried? Arqade works best when you show what you've already tried before, so we can work from there.